# ¿Como mostrar imagenes desde la carpeta Storage/App/tenancy? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, local-storage

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 7 y Multitenant, el tema que tenia que guardar en la BD la ruta donde se guardaba las imagenes, en este caso en la carpeta Storage con su respectivo inquilino unico.

El problema que trate de llamar el helper

```
<img src="{{asset("app/tenancy/tenants/".$model->logo)}}" alt="Logo">
```

pero solo me muestra el ALT nisiquiera un icono de imagen ni nada.

Asi esta ordenado la carpeta Storage con Tenant
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuración del storage

```
'disks' => [
     'tenancy' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root' => storage_path('app/tenancy/tenants/'),
     ],
]
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/tenacy/tenants'),
    ],
```

Asi es como guardo la imagen

```
if ($request->file('logo')) {
     $fileLogo = $request->file('logo');
     //Recupero el tenant actual
     $pathUUI = (app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->website()->uuid)."/public";

     if (Storage::disk('tenancy')->exists($project->logo)) {
          Storage::disk('tenancy')->delete($project->logo);
     }

     $pathLogo = Storage::disk('tenancy')->put($pathUUI,$fileLogo);

     Project::where('id',$project->id)->update(['logo'=>$pathLogo]);
}
```

Ya ingrese a que se publicara la referencia a public del storage pero sigue sin visualizar imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el registro como se guarda en tu bd?

Comment: @Dohko19 me lo guarda desde el 59138... en adelante pero no me muestra la imagen

Comment: `<img src="{{Storage::url("tenancy/tenants/".$model->logo)}}" alt="Logo">
`

Comment: prrueba de ese modo

Comment: No sigue imprimiendome lo que dice alt pero tambien debe ser porque tampoco me reconoce la url del sistema. Eso me imprime en el inspector
```<img src="/storage/tenancy/tenants/5913844249524b82a76008a94e33ae7e/public/iEVk7ClMrlS5FYDik0cJ6Idxsr8uUPCwlgsSDLCE.jpeg" alt="Logo">```

Comment: Puede ser en tu archivo .env coincide con la url? y por ultimo puedes probar con solo <img src="{{Storage::url("$model->logo)}}" alt="Logo">

Comment: Es que si traigo cosas de public en fotos si se muestran pero al trabajar en storage cosa que nunca antes habia trabajado hay no se muestran. Y lo probe lo que me dices y sigo sin traer la imagen. No será que al ser de Storage ya que trabajo con multi inquilino, deberia generar una ruta y de hay descargar la imagen y ejecutar phpa rtisan storage:link?

Comment: para empezar a trabajar con storage si es necesario el storage:link

Comment: otro punto a tomar en cuenta es como guardas tus imagenes

Comment: @Dohko19 ejecute el storage link ademas trate de agregarle una linea más al filesystems agregandole esta linea ```public_path('tenant') => storage_path('app/tenacy/tenants'),``` 

Ejecute storage:link ya me trae ahora la ruta completa pero sigue sin aparecer imagen. La imagen la guardo asi, actualizare el post agreganod como guardo la imagen

Comment: Debes de crear un funcion para descargar la imagen.

Comment: Sigue sin mostrarmela y solo me muestra lo que puse en el atributo alt de la imagen